# Magento Title tag seo

Tags: magento-1.7, seo

I have a magento website [Logtech](http://www.logtech.in) . I have changed the default title and all to my site variables. But when I search in google for `logtech.in` it shows the title `Magento Commerce`.

Comment: Give Google time to re-crawl your pages. The changes don't reflect immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your or any website crawling all searching engines have a certain round robin mechanism, so they will pick your title soon, when your turn comes.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your Google Webmasters Tools Account you can fetch pages for re-indexing.

More information on the steps can be found at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro use webmaster and follow some step.
1. Submit sitemap.xml 
2. Check crowl status.
3. Check robots.txt
4. Use index tool
5. Don't miss data highlighter tool in webmaster this is very important tool index point of view...
If you have confussion and want all index rule check my quora profile. https://www.quora.com/profile/PRADEEP-KUMAR-4135

I hope this answers helpful for you.
Cheers...